# Modifying a deep nested state in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

My reducer looks like this

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { map:[], routes:[], road:null};


export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case TOGGLE_ROUTE_VISIBILITY : return { ...state, routes: action.payload };
            break;
        case SAVE_ROAD_ROUTE : return {...state, routes: action.payload };
            break;
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

and my action looks like this

```
export function toggleVisibility(id, routes){
    const i = _.findIndex(routes, o => { return o.id = id });
    routes[i].visible = !routes[i].visible;
    return {
        type: TOGGLE_ROUTE_VISIBILITY,
        payload: routes
    }
}
```

So my state looks like

```
state:{
    base:
        routes : [
           {id:1, visible:true},
           {id:2, visible:true},
        ]
}}
```

The main problem is setting the data on the routes state. I have a feeling that my approach is incorrect and there's a proper way of saving the routes in the state and still be able to modify and save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to keep actions simple and move all logic into reducers. There is no need to pass routes object into each action.

Here is simple example

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {map: [], routes: [], road: null};

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_ROUTE_VISIBILITY :
            return Object.assign(state, {
                routes: state.routes.map(function (route) {
                    if (route.id === action.id) {
                        route.visible = !route.visible;
                    }
                    return route;
                })
            });
            break;
        case SAVE_ROAD_ROUTE:
            return Object.assign(state, {
                routes: [
                    ...state.routes,
                    {
                        id: action.id, // or just add some ID generator here
                        visible: true
                    }
                ]
            });
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Action

```
export function toggleVisibility(id){
    return {
        type: TOGGLE_ROUTE_VISIBILITY,
        id: id
    }
}
```

Also have a look at [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) which really helps in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass the route ID in your action. You can use some kind of immutability helper to update the state in the reducer, or you can do it more manually. For example, using the React [update](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) add-on:

```js
return update(state, {
  base: {
    routes: {
      [action.payload.routeId]: {
        visible: {
          $apply: function (visible) {
            return !visible;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```